# Boolean Algebra Expression Simplification

Tags: boolean, algebra, simplify, simplification

Hello I have to simplify the first expression which is from a 7 segment Display assignment.
upper case means it is a NOT so for example the first part ZYXW means NOT z AND NOT y AND NOT x AND NOT w. I hope that makes sense.

So the problem is i found the answer for the expression which simplifies to 
a = z + x + yw + YW
however my simplification ends at a = zYX

bellow are the steps for my simplification, could someone identify the problem please.

```
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + ZyxW + Zyxw + zYXw + zYXW
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + ZyxW + Zyxw + zYX(w + W)
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + ZyxW + Zyxw + zYX(1)
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + ZyxW + Zyxw + zYX.1
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + ZyxW + Zyxw + zYX

a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx(W + w) + zYX
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx(1) + zYX
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx.1 + zYX
a = ZYXW + ZYxW + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx + zYX

a = ZYW(X + x) + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW(1) + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW.1 + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + ZYxw + ZyXw + Zyx + zYX

a = ZYW + Zw(xY + Xy) + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + Zw(x.1 + X.1) + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + Zw(x + X) + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + Zw(1) + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + Zw.1 + Zyx + zYX
a = ZYW + Zw + Zyx + zYX

a = Z(YW + w + yz) + zYX
a = Z(Y.1 + yz) + zYX
a = Z(Y = yz) + zYX
a = Z(z) + zYX
a = Z + z + zYX
a = 1 + zYX
a = zYX
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this exercise is for using Karnaugh Maps. With those its quite simple. Just look here: [Karnaugh Map Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

First you create a truth table, like the one at the start of this tutorial.
The 16 rows represent all combinations of your 4 variables. You get the result of a row, by comparing it to your function.

So 0 0 0 0 is equivalent to ZYXW and the solution would be 1 because ZYXW is in your function.

0 0 0 1 would be ZYXw which is not in your function, so the solution is 0.

0 0 1 0 would be ZYxW which is in your function, so the solution is 1.

Do this for all 16 rows. Then go ahead like in the
[Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esvCZJxV_qY).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for answering.  The trouble with link-only answers is they tend to become invalid over time.  It would improve this answer if you could show the user of a K-map in the context of the question.

Comment: We haven't went through that yet : /